# Exponential Map of Stereographic Projection of Sphere (through North Pole)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spherical-geometry, stereographic-projections

Let

$\overline{S}^n_K$ be the stereographic projection of the sphere, and

$S^n_K$ be the sphere with sectional curvature $K$.

Let $\Pi$ be the stereographic projection 
$$
\Pi\colon S^n_K\setminus\{\text{north pole}\}\to\overline{S}_K^n.
$$

---

Then, for example, the distance function on $\overline{S}^n_K$ can be obtained by back-projecting the points to $S^n_K$ and inserting them into the distance formula on $S^n_K$.

$$
d_{\overline{S}^n_K}(x,y)=d_{S^n_K}(\Pi^{-1}(x), \Pi^{-1}(y)).
$$

This formula can then be simplified and gives a distance function on $\overline{S}^n_K$.

---

I know that the exponential map on $S_K^n$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
\exp_{x}\colon T_{x}S^n_K&\to S^n_K\\
u&\mapsto
\cos\left(
\sqrt{K}||u||_{x}
\right)x
+
\frac{
\sin\left(
\sqrt{K}||u||_{x}
\right)
}{
\sqrt{K}||u||_{x}
}
u.
\end{align*}
$$

Now what I'd like to do is to derive is the exponential map on $\overline{S}^n_K$ in a similar fashion.

That means I'd have to back-project $x$ with $\Pi^{-1}$.

Now, how do I transform the tangent vector $u'\in T_x \overline{S}^n_K$ to get the corresponding tangent vector in $u\in T_{\Pi^{-1}(x)}S_K^n$?

$$
u'\in T_x \overline{S}^n_K \quad \to \quad u\in T_{\Pi^{-1}(x)} S^n_K
$$